# remove or hide first few words in jquery ui-helper

Tags: jquery

my code produce the following using jquery ui-helper.And I want to hide/remove the 1000: and 1001: from the li tag. Also I want to disable the draggable feature, can I do tht?

```
   <ul class="available connected-list" style="height: 101px;">

<li class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></li>

<li class="ui-state-default ui-element ui-draggable" title="1000:薯仔咖哩雞 Curry Chicken" style="">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden"></span>1000:薯仔咖哩雞 Curry Chicken
<a href="#" class="action">
<span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
</a>
</li>

<li class="ui-state-default ui-element ui-draggable" title="1001:香脆炸鸡翼 Crispy Fried Chicken Wing" style="">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden"></span>1001:香脆炸鸡翼 Crispy Fried Chicken Wing<a href="#" class="action">
<span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus">
</span>
</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: if jquery generating this code you can replace 1000 and 1001 from it using str_replace()

Answer (score 1):

See this will helps,
http://jsfiddle.net/KLpea/

```
    $( ".your_selector" ).draggable( "disable" ); // TO disable the Jquery UI draggable & Disable the draggable with your specific condition

    $("ul li").html(function(i, html) {
        return html.replace(/\d*:/, "");
    });
```

Comment: $( ".your_selector" ). IN my case, is it $( "ul.connected-list" )?

Comment: You will load a function on dom for draggable. check in that which selector you have used? and use that same in this.